# How to resolve Assembly Reference Error

Tags: c#, .net

I am using Devexpress. By following this link (http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E3863) i wrote this code below. It is generating two errors which i define below. When ever i enter a assembly reference it generates an error i.e.

```
Warning 7 Unknown build error, 'Cannot resolve dependency to assembly 'System.Windows, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' because it has not been preloaded. When using the ReflectionOnly APIs, dependent assemblies must be pre-loaded or loaded on demand through the ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve event.'  LINQServer





<Window x:Class="LINQServer.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:dxg="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/grid"
            xmlns:dxe="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/editors"
                    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
            xmlns:dxsm="clr-namespace:DevExpress.Xpf.Core.ServerMode;assembly=DevExpress.Xpf.Core.v13.1"
            xmlns:dxb="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/bars"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LINQServer"
            xmlns:crud="clr-namespace:LINQServer;assembly=CRUDBehavior"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
        <Window.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="EditRecordTemplate">
                <StackPanel Margin="8" MinWidth="200">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition />
                            <RowDefinition />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Text="ID:" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,6,4" />
                        <dxe:TextEdit x:Name="txtID" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" EditValue="{Binding Path=Id, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="0,0,0,4" />
                        <TextBlock Text="Name:" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,6,4" />
                        <dxe:TextEdit x:Name="txtCompany" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" EditValue="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="0,0,0,4" />
                    </Grid>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
            <local:newsEntites x:Key="newsEntites" />
        </Window.Resources>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <dxg:GridControl x:Name="grid" SelectionMode="Row">
                <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <crud:EntityServerModeCRUDBehavior x:Name="helper"
                        NewRowForm="{StaticResource ResourceKey=EditRecordTemplate}"
                        EditRowForm="{StaticResource ResourceKey=EditRecordTemplate}"
                        EntityType="{x:Type local:Item}"
                        ObjectContext="{StaticResource ResourceKey=newsntites}"
                        AllowKeyDownActions="True">
                        <crud:EntityServerModeCRUDBehavior.DataSource>
                            <dxsm:EntityServerModeDataSource KeyExpression="Id" QueryableSource="{Binding Items, Source={StaticResource DatabaseEntites}}" />
                        </crud:EntityServerModeCRUDBehavior.DataSource>
                    </crud:EntityServerModeCRUDBehavior>
                </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
                    <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Id">
                        <dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                            <dxe:TextEditSettings AllowNullInput="False" />
                        </dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                    </dxg:GridColumn>
                    <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Name">
                        <dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                            <dxe:TextEditSettings AllowNullInput="False" />
                        </dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                    </dxg:GridColumn>
                </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
                <dxg:GridControl.View>
                    <dxg:TableView Name="view" AutoWidth="True" NavigationStyle="Row" />
                </dxg:GridControl.View>
            </dxg:GridControl>
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <Button Height="22" Width="60" Command="{Binding Path=NewRowCommand, ElementName=helper}">Add</Button>
                <Button Height="22" Width="60" Command="{Binding Path=RemoveRowCommand, ElementName=helper}" Margin="6,0,6,0">Remove</Button>
                <Button Height="22" Width="60" Command="{Binding Path=EditRowCommand, ElementName=helper}">Edit</Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Window>
```

ERROR LIST:

```
       Error    1   The tag 'Interaction.Behaviors' does not exist in XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity'. Line 39 Position 14.  C:\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\LINQServer\LINQServer\MainWindow.xaml  39  14  LINQServer


        Error   2   The type or namespace name 'Interactivity' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?)    C:Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\LINQServer\LINQServer\EntityServerModeCRUDBehavior.cs   4   22  LINQServer

Error   6   The attachable property 'DataSource' was not found in type 'EntityServerModeCRUDBehavior'.  C:\Users\must\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\LINQServer\LINQServer\MainWindow.xaml   46  22  LINQServer
```

Error   5   The type 'crud:EntityServerModeCRUDBehavior' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.   C:\Users\must\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\LINQServer\LINQServer\MainWindow.xaml   40  18  LINQServer

How can i resolve these errors? can you answer my question?

Answer (score 3):

Right click on your project file in Solution Explorer. Select Add Reference, go to the Assemblies tab and find System.Windows. Add the reference and voila.